# adding more fields to registration form using membership on MySql and MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, mysql-connector

i started a site based on asp.net MVC 3 and MySql
i got the membership to work with the MySQL .NET connector
so with the default application you get with a new project of mvc 3 i have a working register form and a working login form

but... how do i add more fields to the registration form?
i know how to add them my model and to the page.. but how do i make the membership keep this new data ill get for the user?
will i have to make the columns in the database by myself? or does membership knows how to create them automaticly somehow?

i only want 3 more fields for the registration...

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you this solution.

1. Create a table called `UserDetails`
2. Add a field that point to the `UserId`

You're done.

Now you need some class to retrieve thoses fields based on the `UserId`. You could also implement your own `MembershipProvider` and add a method like `GetUserDetail()` which return an object containing your extra fields.

This is based on an official ASP.NET article : http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/storing-additional-user-information-cs

Comment: Where to write code to insert values in UserDetails while SignUp Process? Because I don't see any insertion code in Account/Register.aspx.cs

Answer (score 10):

take a look at your AccountModels.cs file. It contains

```
public class RegisterModel
{ 
   // User name, Email Adress, Password, Password confirmation already there

   // you can add something like below
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nickname")]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have a new property in your model you need to update the view. In the Views > Account > Register.cshtml you should add

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nickname )
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Nickname )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Nickname )
        </div>
```

When you're done with that you need to update the registration logic to use your new property. Go to AccountController and find

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
              //
              // this would be a good place for you to put your code to do something with model.Nickname
              //                    
              return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

If you want to persist that information to Users ASP.NET Profile, you need this in Web.config

```
<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  <properties>
    <add name="Nickname" defaultValue="False" type="System.String" />
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Then in your code - you can do

```
var userProfile = ProfileBase.Create(model.UserName);
```

to get/set your properties in Profile

Comment: you wrote this:// this would be a good place for you to put your code to do something with model.Nickname
but what code will that be?... another call to the database? this didnt solve my question on how i can make the membership do it. i read something about profile base. is that it?.. is the only way 2 calls to the database?

Comment: It is up to you how you want to handle data persistance part. You can either use Profiles (that some find not flexible enough) or you can initialize your DataContext. See the updated answer

Comment: After doing `userProfile.SetPropertyValue("Nickname", "my nickname");` do `userProfile.Save()` for persistance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to create fields for Age and Gender. you can first of all create UI for registration in the corresponding Registration view. it means creating input fields for Age and Gender. then in the AccountController go to Register view and add Age and Gender fields in ApplicationUser object (that is already declared). And there you go.

Detailed information on this can be found http://blog.falafel.com/customize-mvc-5-application-users-using-asp-net-identity-2-0/