# MVC 3 add more fields then provided to account controler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-accounts

Can somebody please help me?
I want to add more fields to account controller than is provided. I want to see these fields in a table as well. I add fields in a Register class. And I am not sure about ID field I want to use auto increment but do not know how if I do not see a table. In normal database it will do automatically. Thanks.
my 
**Account model:**

public class ChangePasswordModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Current password")]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class LogOnModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    [Display(Name = "Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "First line of address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "DOB => dd/mm/yyyy")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [PostCode(ErrorMessage= "PostCode is not valid")]
    [Display(Name = "Post Code")]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}

public class PostCodeAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public PostCodeAttribute()
        : base(
            @"([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-
                hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-
                Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})")
    {
        ErrorMessage = "PostCode is invalid";
    }
}
```

Then in AccountController I can create user which has same data fields in a table but Membership do not have this option only
 Membership.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [SimpleMembership](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx) (it's the future) and using your own schema, and then using NuGet to [use it with MVC 3](http://anderly.com/2011/08/11/using-simplemembership-in-mvc3/).

Answer (score 0):

This is "classic" ASP.NET but should help

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/storing-additional-user-information-cs

(From here [adding more fields to registration form using membership on MySql and MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369055/adding-more-fields-to-registration-form-using-membership-on-mysql-and-mvc-3))